# Fill a <select> using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So I want to add a dropdown in my form that will display numbers from 1 to 999 . 
I have tried to do it using JS but it doesn't work 
Here is what I have tried so far :

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = fillDropDown(); 

function fillDropDown() { 
var ddl = document.getElementById( 'myDropdown' ); 
var theOption = new Option; 
var x; 
var i; 

for(i = 0; i < 999; i++) { 
x = i + 1; 
theOption.text = x; 
theOption.value = x; 
ddl.options[i] = theOption; 
} 
} 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myForm"> 
<select id="myDropdown"></select> 
</form>
</body>
```

But it doesn't work . 
Here is a jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/j3nLxptn/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if you instantiate the option inside the loop:

```
 for (i = 0; i < 999; i++) {
        var theOption = new Option;
        x = i + 1;
        theOption.text = x;
        theOption.value = x;
        ddl.options[i] = theOption;
    }
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/j3nLxptn/1/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are always reusing the same option element. You have to create a new [`Option`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement.Option) instance at every iteration and that you can use [`add`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement) to actually append select options.

Also note that the `Option` constructor can take `text` and `value` parameters.

```
for (i = 0; i < 999; i++) {
    x = i + 1;
    ddl.add(new Option(x, x), null);
}
```